# Setup website with / prefixed URLs to run in sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to host a website that is setup with links in the format /css/file.css and /js/file.js and I'd like to set it up in a sub-directory on an existing domain for demo purposes.

So
/demo/css/file.css is the true path

But the demo/index.php references
/css/file.css

I can have a custom .htaccess file within the sub-directory.

Is this possible without touching the main site on my domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request is for `/css/file.css` then rules have to be placed in root .htaccess not in `/demo/` directory.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?:css|js)/.+)$ /demo/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking.  That won't work as it will likely break the main site.  I'll change the URLs to relative and see how I get on.  It's a favour for a client, I don't want to modify the code too much as he wants to use it as a testbed for some modifications

Comment: Only other way I can think of is using `HTTP_REFERER`. If `HTTP_REFERER` contains `/demo/` then apply above rule from root .htaccess

Comment: I've gone with the easy option and told him he will need to use a sub-domain

Comment: Yes that is always the best solution.